# How do I retrieve stats about my iTunes Match account?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I wonder how I can get details on my iTunes Match account. Especially I am interested in how many songs were uploaded to the cloud. Even better: which songs are uploaded, wich ones were matched with iTune songs.

EDIT: I just found out that a smart playlist would help for that. But then I noticed that I really am interested in "how many songs can I still add to my iCloud until I reach the 25,000 songs limit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a smartlist that only includes songs with the status Matched, Uploaded and Purchased.